# Removing nan by an index in an existing for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
import shap
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

I try to run a regression and calculate shap values in a loop. The goal is  to regress a set of 'features' on 'X' using the sample weight 'w' and put the result in an data frame after the calculation.

```
X = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('Q27'))]
features = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('Total' ,'Q25C', 'Loyal', 'Image'))]
w = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('WEIGHT_Both'))]


def reg_loop(label):
   y = features[label]

   #  rm_indx_X = list(X.dropna().index)
   #  X = X.loc[rm_indx_X]
   #  y = y.loc[rm_indx_X]
   #  w = w.loc[rm_indx_X]

   lm = LinearRegression()

   fit = lm.fit(X, y, sample_weight = w['WEIGHT_Both'])

   explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(fit, X, feature_dependence="independent")

   shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

   shap_values_abs = np.absolute(shap_values)
   means_norm = shap_values_abs.mean(axis = 0)/1
   idx = np.argsort(means_norm)
   means = np.array(means_norm)[idx]
   return(means)

   pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(i) for i in features.columns}, 
                           X.columns.values.tolist(),
                           columns = features.columns)

   pred_df
```

This works fine. However, I have missing values in the data which have to be removed before the calculation of the regression. To do so I try to remove the missing values by the row index (see code block with the hashtags). If I do this I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment
```

It works fine if don't use the loop:

```
y = features['Total']
    
rm_indx_X = list(X.dropna().index)

X = X.loc[rm_indx_X]
    
y = y.loc[rm_indx_X]
    
w = w.loc[rm_indx_X]

lm = LinearRegression()

fit = lm.fit(X, y, sample_weight = w['WEIGHT_Both'])

explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(fit, X, feature_dependence="independent")

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

shap_values_abs = np.absolute(shap_values)
means_norm = shap_values_abs.mean(axis = 0)/1
idx = np.argsort(means_norm)
means = np.array(means_norm)[idx]

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(means, 
                       X.columns.values.tolist(),
                       columns = ['Total'])
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Here is an example of the data:

```
df.head(3).to_dict()

{'WEIGHT_Both': {0: 0.2486, 1: 0.97319, 2: 1.02554},
 'Total': {0: 5.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0},
 'Q25C': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Visit': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Buy': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Loyal': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Image': {0: 6.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_1': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_2': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_3': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_4': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_5': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_6': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_7': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_8': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_9': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_10': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_11': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_12': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_13': {0: 3.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_14': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_15': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_16': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_17': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_18': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_19': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_20': {0: 3.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q27_21': {0: 4.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_1': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_2': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_3': {0: 3.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_4': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_5': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_6': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_7': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_8': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_9': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'Q28_10': {0: 2.0, 1: nan, 2: nan}}
```

---

Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, neither of the solutions are working.

a) `def reg_loop(X, w, features, label)`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-e0c366e7b016> in <module>
----> 1 pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(i, X, w, features) for i in features.columns}, 
      2                        X.columns.values.tolist(),
      3                        columns = features.columns)
      4 
      5 i

<ipython-input-85-e0c366e7b016> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(i, X, w, features) for i in features.columns}, 
      2                        X.columns.values.tolist(),
      3                        columns = features.columns)
      4 
      5 i

<ipython-input-79-5fa43fb8a955> in reg_loop(X, w, features, label)
      1 def reg_loop(X, w, features, label):
      2 
----> 3     y = features[label]
      4 
      5     rm_indx_X = list(X.dropna().index)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2912         # Do we have a (boolean) DataFrame?
   2913         if isinstance(key, DataFrame):
-> 2914             return self._getitem_frame(key)
   2915 
   2916         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_frame(self, key)
   3007     def _getitem_frame(self, key):
   3008         if key.values.size and not is_bool_dtype(key.values):
-> 3009             raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')
   3010         return self.where(key)
   3011 

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

b) `global X, w, features`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-c989511bed01> in <module>
----> 1 pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(i) for i in features.columns}, 
      2                        X.columns.values.tolist(),
      3                        columns = features.columns)
      4 
      5 pred_df

<ipython-input-99-c989511bed01> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(i) for i in features.columns}, 
      2                        X.columns.values.tolist(),
      3                        columns = features.columns)
      4 
      5 pred_df

<ipython-input-98-bf1dfa2ead64> in reg_loop(label)
     13     lm = LinearRegression()
     14 
---> 15     fit = lm.fit(X, y, sample_weight = w['WEIGHT_Both'])
     16 
     17     explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(fit, X, feature_dependence="independent")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    461         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    462         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 463                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    464 
    465         if sample_weight is not None and np.atleast_1d(sample_weight).ndim > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 722                         dtype=None)
    723     else:
    724         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when you assign `X =` and `w =` inside the function, python creates locally scoped `X` and `w`, so then it doesn't see the global `X` and `w` anymore.

Either pass in the variables as function params (`features` isn't strictly needed in this case, but it's good practice to clarify the scoping):

```py
def reg_loop(X, w, features, label):
    ...

pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(X, w, features, i) for i in features.columns}, ...
```

Or define them as `global` inside the function:

```py
def reg_loop(label):
    global X, w, features
    ...
```

---

Here is the full code block that works on my end:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
import shap
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('Q27'))]
features = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('Total' ,'Q25C', 'Loyal', 'Image'))]
w = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(('WEIGHT_Both'))]

def reg_loop(X, w, features, label):
    y = features[label]

    rm_indx_X = list(X.dropna().index)
    X = X.loc[rm_indx_X]
    y = y.loc[rm_indx_X]
    w = w.loc[rm_indx_X]

    lm = LinearRegression()

    fit = lm.fit(X, y, sample_weight = w['WEIGHT_Both'])

    explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(fit, X, feature_dependence="independent")

    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

    shap_values_abs = np.absolute(shap_values)
    means_norm = shap_values_abs.mean(axis = 0)/1
    idx = np.argsort(means_norm)
    means = np.array(means_norm)[idx]
    return(means)

pred_df = pd.DataFrame({i: reg_loop(X, w, features, i) for i in features.columns}, 
                       X.columns.values.tolist(),
                       columns = features.columns)
pred_df
```